How to Migrate Data from a Table with 6 Million Rows in SQL Server Without Overloading the Database
I am facing difficulties migrating data from a table with 6 million rows to another table in a SQL Server database due to resource limitations. The database is relatively small, and when I send 100,000 rows at a time, the DTU usage spikes to 100%, which compromises the performance and stability of the system.
I have tried several approaches for this migration, including:

Batch processing with Python
Using the INSERT SELECT command
Importing data from a CSV file to the destination table

However, all these approaches have resulted in database overload and have not been effective for a smooth migration.
What are the best practices or techniques to migrate large volumes of data without causing high resource utilization in the database? Is there an efficient way to break the migration into smaller steps without making the processing take too many hours, or optimize the process to minimize the impact on the database?

You mentioned DTUs which leads me to think you're on Azure SQL. Can you temporarily increase the DTUs for the duration of this process? I know it sounds big, but 6m rows should only take a couple of minutes. One of the (if not the main) advantages of the cloud is elastic capacity. You may as well use it.

Are you using Azure SQL or On Premise Sql Server ?. DTU directly related to Azure but the tag is Sql-Server. Then you could mention overall increase of cpu, disk and memory of Sql Server.

How you tried to import data from a CSV file to the destination table ? by using Management Studio import - export - DTS utility or by developing a Python Code

did you try SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)? It will work effectively for large data migrations, including the ability to control batch sizes, handle errors, and manage performance.

There is a similar (not identical!) question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790548/

You can try the following conceptual example.
It will work starting from SQL Server 2012 onwards.
It is using the OFFSET / FETCH, i.e. pagination functionality.
The only parameter that needs to be manually specified is @NumberOfBatchesTotal.
At the end, you can see the process progress in SSMS in the Messages pane.
SQL
-- DDL and data population, start
DECLARE @source TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, [Description] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @source VALUES 
   (1, 'One')
   , (2, 'Two')
   , (3, 'Three')
   , (4, 'Four')
   , (5, 'Five')
   , (6, 'Six')
   , (7, 'Seven')
   , (8, 'Eight')
   , (9, 'Nine')
   , (10, 'Ten')
   , (11, 'Elleven')
   , (12, 'Twelve')
   , (13, 'Thirteen');

DECLARE @target TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, [Description] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
-- DDL and data population, end

DECLARE @BatchNo INT = 1
   , @NumberOfBatchesTotal DECIMAL = 3
   , @RowsPerBatch INT
   , @RowTotal INT;

-- To calculate # of rows per each Batch
SET @RowTotal = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @source);
SET @RowsPerBatch = CEILING(@RowTotal/@NumberOfBatchesTotal);

WHILE @BatchNo <= @NumberOfBatchesTotal
BEGIN
    INSERT @target (ID, Description)
    SELECT * FROM @source
    ORDER BY ID
        OFFSET (@BatchNo - 1) * @RowsPerBatch ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @RowsPerBatch ROWS ONLY;

    PRINT @BatchNo;
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';   -- Wait 10 SECONDS
    SET @BatchNo += 1;
END;

-- test
SELECT * FROM @target;

Messages pane
(13 rows affected)

(5 rows affected)
1

(5 rows affected)
2

(3 rows affected)
3

(13 rows affected)


Based on the assumption of your system is Sql Server my solution is as follows.
First: Dedection of the problem.
Your attempt of

Batch processing with Python

Using the INSERT SELECT command


could result of many reasons. We dont know your queries, commands
(You could heavy read, delete, update, source-destionation). Actually these steps are hiding the source of the problem.
On the other hand

Importing data from a CSV file to the destination table

shows that you are facing Transaction Log problem due to write - insert transactions and you are using full recovery model. Again this is meaningful if you used Management Studio Import - Export, DTS utility.
If you developed your own process with Python then this also could hide the source of the problem.
Depending on the importance of the problem (developer person critical, company wide critical) we could suggest many solutions.
Second: Solution Steps
1.) Make a full backup. First for safety of migration process changes but actually to release the allocated space of transaction logs. Means you will empty the log file's content.
Then change recovery model as SIMPLE.
2.) Increase the Autogrowth size of your database files. Never write 1, 2, 3 MB. You can set Autogrowth to 256, 512, 1024 MB like the picture below.
This will decrease the transaction log file's growth frequency.
After migration process you can set to an ideal disk value. Lets say 64 MB.

3.) If it is possible add a new log file on another physical disk. After migration you can remove it.
4.) Script all the indexes of the destination table then disable or drop all indexes, except Primary Key.
5.) Do not delete records of source table in the same transaction. Means first read from source table > insert into destination table. Do this for batch and whole process. After migration you can check - compare records if needed. After safety period of few days you could delete source table.
6.) Migration query.
DECLARE @BATCHCOUNT INT = 1
DECLARE @LASTID INT

WHILE @BATCHCOUNT<=100
BEGIN

    SET @LASTID=ISNULL((SELECT MAX([ID]) FROM [DEST_TABLE]),0)


    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [DEST_TABLE] ON

    INSERT INTO [DEST_TABLE]
          ([ID], C1, C2, C3,..)

    SELECT TOP (10000) [ID], C1, C2, C3,..
           FROM SOURCE_TABLE
           WHERE ID>@LASTID
           ORDER BY ID 

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [DEST_TABLE] OFF

    SET @BATCHCOUNT = @BATCHCOUNT + 1

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30';

END

Basic parameters of the query are
@BATCHCOUNT<=100, SELECT TOP (10000), WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30';

You can manage them for your conditions.
I used WAITFOR DELAY to release the server resources temporarily for other processes.
7.) If your source table update - delete frequency is high and you need to do the job while working hours.
Before migration process

Write a trigger for source table to update - delete the destination table record also.
As an alternative to trigger add a modified datetime column into source table. After migration check those records and modify the target table.

By these way you can run the migraiton process safely for days under data integrity of the source table.
8:) If you can run migration process at night, means outside of the working ours. Then you dont need to write a trigger and add a modified datetime column.
Add a Sql Job** and in the first step of the job add the Migration Query, Schedule to work at night at once or schedule for every 10 minutes.
9.) After migration and controls, do not use Delete statement instead use Truncate statement for the source table. If you use delete then again milions of record deletion tried to be written into transaction log file.
